How to open this flush mounted light fixture

There are two small screws on each side.   I removed them but the fixture seems very mounted. I stuck a wide chisel in between the frame and ceiling and was able to slightly wiggle it.   I feel like there’s a trick to slide the glass or fold down the bottom and I just don’t see it

Two screws on each side says to me you're on the right track.  Imagine the black frame is mounted on a metal plate.  Make sure your chisel is positioned to separate them and not to lever the inner plate off the ceiling.   Just barely insert the chisel not more than the thickness of the frame.

try lifting the bottom panel

I tried pushing up on the glass potion of the bottom

try pushing the side panels ... maybe one moves and reveals a screw
